# Single function to return file contents as a string

Tags: files, string

I'm wondering if there's a terse (i.e. single function) approach for reading a file's content given its path and returning it as a string.

My go-to has been:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert-file-contents some-path)
  (buffer-string))
  => "it's a short file"
```

but a helper function defined per project or this two-functions-and-a-macro copy-pasta seem unnecessary.  Is there a utility function or common pattern I'm missing?

Judging from the existence of `gntp-file-string`, `ffap-file-exists-string`, `org-file-contents`, and a few others I'm guessing there is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not. You can `report-emacs-bug` and suggest that one be included.

One reason I can think of for *not* including such a function is that there are different reasonable ways to handle errors. E.g. if the file is not readable, what should the function do? Return `nil`? Return empty string (`""`)? Signal an error?

**Update**: `f-read-text` in `f.el` does what you want.

Comment: And for that reason I can understand it not being in elisp itself.  It would probably be a good addition to `f.el`.  `org-file-contents` seems like a reasonable implementation (it includes a *noerror* parameter), but as you say there are subtle variations of behavior one might desire.  Per POLA, however; I would consider `""` to indicate an empty (zero-length) file.

Comment: [`f-read-text`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el/blob/v0.19.0/f.el#L209) in `f.el` does what you want.

Comment: Grrr.  and I knew about f-read-bytes.  I'm not sure how I missed that.  The global symbol table needs a synonym table! :-P

Comment: Another subtlety is whether to use `insert-file-contents` or `insert-file-contents-literally`.  Often you'll want to use the latter, but it not dealing with encodings sucks.

Comment: "if _condition x_, what should the function do" can be asked for almost any function. So, I doubt this has anything to do with it.